# What is google API and framework API

Tags: android

I m confused about google API and android platform SDK API. are they same ? if not, What are the each used for?

Comment: It is like using functionality of google, like Maps and others. for that you have to add API level from Google API.

Comment: where do I get offline docs for platform API ?

Answer (score 7):

Android is developed by Google, but can also be used without any Google services. So the [Android platform SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) can be used for developing *Android applications*. If you however want to use any *Google services* in your Android Application, you should use the [Google API Java Client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs).

Answer (score 1):

Google api is used for using google specific services like google map or google admob or google fusion. These generally contact google server to fetch data.
However, android platform sdk api is not google specific. It provides interface for application development. These may or may not require internet(depending on what you use it for)