# Android eclipse application with MapView

Tags: eclipse, android-layout, android-mapview

I am new to eclipse. I have a old application that is compatible for 2.2 android version. Basically this application display google map using Map View. I just want to make some text changes in this application for deployment. But i'm having issue while debug. It get crashed. Here is error window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing a similar situation from time to time I have to have the following for the old project:

- Eclipse Luna (no other eclipse works)
- Old version of Android SDK (update it to far and nothing works)

The quirks of my situation may be specific to my project but maybe they'll help. Android + Eclipse is not fun, convert to Android studio if you have the possibility:

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html

Comment: Not possible to migrate that project. I have selected the Google API's 2.2 Project Build Target. Is that correct or not? @Adam

Comment: Compare with what you have in your AndroidManifest, if it is the same it should work. Maybe this could be of interest as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084413/what-is-the-difference-between-google-apis-in-android-sdk , I don't think I can provide any more help than that. I don't recognize your specific errors

Comment: Thanks @Adam, I will compare with that.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to convert your project to **Android studio** and then fix your issues because some of the them will not work in **Eclipse** and might be some libraries are not supported in **Eclipse**.

See this how to [Convert Eclipse project to Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html)

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084413/what-is-the-difference-between-google-apis-in-android-sdk), it might be helpful for you.